# List all CSS attribute selectors on page?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, css-selectors

Chrome's CSS Overview feature always shows 21 type selectors in our app, but I've scoured our code, even third party references, and can't find these selectors. Is there some way I can list them out?

I understand these can take a toll on performance in some circumstances, which is part of my interest in tracking them down. The other part of my interest is just to understand where these come from. Are they in the user agent stylesheet? I have no idea...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this

The solution I made was that I wrote a Python script to read through all files in a particular directory searching for any strings that match a specific regex and extracting file name and line if the regex hits.

it would be best if you also handled 3rd party references.

another point is that these selectors might be a 4th party resource "Your 3rd party resource uses another external resource" which will make it harder for you to scrape because you will need to handle scraping dependencies somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In our case there are no 4th party resources.